# How do I avoid line break of two big iframes?

Tags: css

two iframes should be forced to be shown as cols, can it be done with css?

Example code:

```
<!-- if I inc width to "800", the iframes should still be as cols, (regardless of window size) !-->
<div style="width:100%;overflow-x:scroll;">
<iframe width="200" height="200" src="http://www.slashdot.net"></iframe>
<iframe width="200" height="200" src="http://freshmeat.net"></iframe>
</div>
```

Please see:
http://jsfiddle.net/7rCSu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `white-space:nowrap;font-size:0` to the containing `<div>` will force the `<iframe>`s to be rendered next to each other.

The `font-size:0` removes the white space between the bottom of the `<iframe>`s and the container and the `white-space:nowrap` stops the browser adding breaks to fill line boxes.

Or you can drop the `font-size:0` and put the `<iframe>` elements on the same line in the markup. You still need the `white-space:nowrap` rule though.

Comment: Clever, I didn't think of using `nowrap`- I was going to suggest doing `width: 50%;` and `float: left|right`.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the div not to wrap:

```
<div style="width:100%;overflow-x:scroll;white-space: nowrap;">
<iframe width="800" height="200" src="http://www.slashdot.net"></iframe>
<iframe width="800" height="200" src="http://freshmeat.net"></iframe>
</div>
```

(tested on Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/7rCSu/2/)

Comment: @user247245, what was not enough? This has the same basic method as the accepted answer, and it solves the problem presented.

Answer (score 0):

Although not fully [cross-browser compatible](http://caniuse.com/flexbox), you can use [CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) to display them in a single row.

```
div {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rCSu/1/).